# Dynamically set ImageView height for Image to fill ImageView width in Aspect fit mode

Tags: ios, swift, image, imageview, height

is it possible to get value of height of ImageView that image would fill ImageView's width in Aspect Fit contentMode?

Comment: You should find your answer in [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+aspect+fit+resize+uiimageview).

Comment: well thank you :) You helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

height = image.height * imageView.width/image.width

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: You can get ImageView Height with this formule, that image will fill imageView width